# Plotly Express: Make colorbar static in animation

Tags: python, plotly, colorbar, plotly-python, choropleth

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62795331/python-can-i-make-the-colorbar-static-in-a-plotly-time-series-choropleth) but the solution is not working for me. Maybe it's because I am generating the map via `px` rather than `go`.

I am trying to make the colorbar static, but I am not able to achieve that properly. I added `z`, `zmax` and `zmin` to the traces but it results in weird behaviour. In the provided example here, it makes the entire map static. (in my original dataframe, it shows false values on some countries) What am I doing wrong here, any guidance would be appreciated.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder()

fig = px.choropleth(df, locations='iso_alpha', color='gdpPercap', animation_frame=df.year.astype(str),
                        projection ='equirectangular')
    
# fig.update_traces(z=df['lifeExp'],zmin=0, zmax=100)
# for idx,frame in enumerate(fig.frames):
#     frame.data[0].update(z=df['lifeExp'], zmin=0, zmax=100)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting an animation group?

Comment: Animation groups would be columns like `country` and `continent`, right? Could you elaborate more as to what kind of a group could help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, adding `range_color` to the main function call and specifying the range (min,max) does the trick here. I used the min and max of the `gdpPercap` feature itself, but they other values can be used too.

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder()

fig = px.choropleth(df, locations='iso_alpha', color='gdpPercap', animation_frame=df.year.astype(str),
                        projection ='equirectangular', range_color=(min(df.gdpPercap), max(df.gdpPercap)))
fig.show()
```

[image]